# SQL with variable conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Today I will ask an easy (probably almost stupid question) according to SQL sentences.

I'm dealing with SELECT querys where I have some conditions but nor always all of them. I will explain with an example.

Imagine a simple table Person [id, name, surname]

I want to get the id of a Person... I will always ask for the name, but not always ask for the surname, so the query will depend on the parameters of the php function... the query could be:

```
SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name; (if parameter surname = null)
```

or
`SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name and surname = $surname;` (if parameter surname is defined)

I have two posible codes to get it, but I think it is not optimized

**Option 1:**

```
if ($surname) {
    SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name and surname = $surname;
else{
    SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name";
if ($surname) { $sql = $sql + " and surname = $surname"; }
```

I think the best option is the second option while the parameters could increase, but I don't know if it could be a flexible parameter to introduce in the query depends on a null parameter.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `... name = $name and ($surname IS NULL or surname = $surname)`.

Comment: The best solution is to use prepared Statements and the code snipped of @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

You might Want to split the query and concatenate:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Person WHERE 1=1";
if(isset($name))
{
       $sql.= " AND name='$name'";    
}
if(isset($surname))
{
       $sql.= " AND surname='$surname'";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I can provide is:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name = $name and ($surname IS NULL or surname = $surname)";
```

Comment: I just saw that @jarlh has posted the same thing as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking! This is a very common situation, and Sanzeeb's answer is the most common response. Be aware, however, that you are chopping up your precious sql, and in future you'll need to attach a debugger and trap your sql on the fly to see what request is actually hitting your DB.

A better approach is to do it all in sql, as follows...

```
var sql = @"
SELECT id FROM Person where name = $name
AND ( surname = $surname or $surname is null)
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
";
```

The readability of your request is maintained. OPTION(RECOMPILE) may be overkill in this situation, but is recommended for optional parameters because it allows the db to optimise for the specific combination of parameters supplied.

A much better option would be to paste the above request into a [QueryFirst](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU5PjljpHPAhWFiRoKHaK1AN4QFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2Feaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb&usg=AFQjCNHtY4UcTC5dARyn9uJgOyZPZcuhrw&sig2=ZFHXKfgc2nAPHVjDK3g7mQ) .sql template, and remove all temptation of innapropriate touching of your SQL! Among the many things QueryFirst will help with, it will automatically convert null in your C# to DBNull.Value, hence NULL in your SQL.